# AssertErrorProc on C++ builder XE4

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, assert

I am studying AssertErrorProc on C++ Builder XE4.
I found the delphi code as follows.

```
procedure AssertErrorHandler(
    const iMsg, iFilename: String;
    const iLineNo: Integer;
    const iAddress: Pointer);
var
    Err: String;
begin
    Err :=
      Format(
        '%s (%s line %d @ %x)',
        [iMsg, iFilename, iLineNo, Integer(iAddress)]);
    ShowMessage(Err);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    AssertErrorProc = AssertErrorHandler;
    Assert(false);
end;
```

I treid to convert the above into C++ code as follows.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::AssertErrorHandler(const String iMsg,
    const String iFilename, const int iLineNo,
    const void* iAddress)

{
    String Err;

    Err = Format(L"%s (%s line %d @ %x)",
        [iMsg, iFilename, iLineNo, Integer(iAddress)]);  // E2188
    ShowMessage(Err);

}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    AssertErrorProc = AssertErrorHandler;  // E2235, E2268
    Assert(false);
}
```

I received two errors in compiling the code.

1. at Format() statement (E2188)
2. at assignment of AssertErrorHandler (E2235, E2268)

I appreciate any information I should modify the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above approach is usable only in Delphi, In C++ you should define custom assert as macro:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #undef assert
    #define assert(condition) if(!condition) assertHandler(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, #condition);
#endif

void assertHandler(const char *fileName, int line, const char *function,
    const char *condition)
{
    char message[255];
    wsprintfA(message, "Assertion failed at %s line %d inside %s condition: %s",
        fileName, line, function, condition);
    ShowMessage(message);
    abort();
}
```

Usage:

```
assert(myVar > 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So, the conversion of the delphi code didn't work for C++. I appreciate that you gave me the example code for C++. It helps a lot. Using #undef and redefine the assert macro never occurred to my mind.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you exactly mean. Put above code in a unit (or in a single header file) and every time you need to assert, use defined "assert" macro, for example assert(MyFunction(param) == 0)

Comment: Note that you can simply convert above delphi code to C++ as: void __fastcall CppAssertErrorProc(const UnicodeString Message,
 const UnicodeString Filename, int LineNumber, void * ErrorAddr); AssertErrorProc = CppAssertErrorProc; but It doesn't work because the "Assert" command is undefined in C++ and "CppAssertErrorProc" is never called by assert (assert is C++ predefined macro).

Comment: Thank you very much. My comment may be misleading. But what I would like to say was that your reply helped a lot. I appreciate. Thank you also for the further comment on the CppAssertErrorProc.